# Get a list of folders from a url in java

Tags: java, file, url, jakarta-ee

I am trying to get the list of folders from the url in java. For example if the user gives url like 
    http://hostname/abc/def/ 
Then it has to return all the folders within def. Can anyone help me on this??

Comment: It is impossible to do

Comment: Are you trying to write a server side component to **generate** the list of folders or do you want to get this information from an arbitrary host and folder?  If you're writing a component on the server side then this is pretty straight forward.  If you're on the client side then, as @Andremoniy says, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is a directory and there is not index.htm(l?) or default.htm(l?) present, then surfing to that URL would return a directory.  Just write a few lines of code to interact with the Web server at //hostname over NVT, sending the GET directive and the HTTP 1/1 (or whatever it is). You'll have to parse the returned text, since it has extraneous junk and formatting, not just a list of contained files and directories.

Comment: No, even if there is not a "default" file like index.html the directory may or may not be listed.  In Apache HTTPD, for example, it depends on how you've configured [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html).  Other servers have different methods for displaying directory contents or not.